# Programmatically configure WCF client binding to access SSL + Soap 1.1 + Basic Auth

Tags: wcf, soap, ssl, cxf, basic-authentication

I'm trying to write a C# WCF client (generated by svcutil from wsdl) to access a CXF (java) service implementing the same wsdl.

The service is working fine but I'm having trouble connecting to it on my C# client because the CXF is configured with SSL + Soap 1.1 + Basic Auth.

So far I've tried the following:
[Why would Basic Auth not work with my WCF client to Java SOAP Web Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742793/why-would-basic-auth-not-work-with-my-wcf-client-to-java-soap-web-service)

```
new BasicHttpBinding()
            {
                Security =
                    {
                        Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
                        Transport =
                            {
                                ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic,
                                ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None
                            },
                        Message =
                            {
                                ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName,
                                AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default
                            }
                    }
            }

var client = new WebServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

But it doesn't seem to send the Auth Header correctly.

I've also tried adding the header manually as outlined by http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4f8ab001-dafa-4347-bc41-95255ecc9230. but I am not satisfied that this being the best solution.

Can any WCF expert outline a way of creating a binding programmatically that supports SSL + Soap 1.1 + Basic Auth?

Following is the header sent with WCF

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [13620] ConnectStream#64929093 - Sending headers
{
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://api.test.com/services/GetThings"
Host: api.test.com
Content-Length: 552
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
}
```

While this is the proper header sent by SoapUI

```
Mon May 13 15:33:08 EDT 2013:DEBUG:>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
Mon May 13 15:33:08 EDT 2013:DEBUG:>> "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
Mon May 13 15:33:08 EDT 2013:DEBUG:>> "SOAPAction: "http://api.test.com/services/GetThings"[\r][\n]"
Mon May 13 15:33:08 EDT 2013:DEBUG:>> "Authorization: Basic bXliVlcHJpbQbWwOTkxMjg=[\r][\n]"
Mon May 13 15:33:08 EDT 2013:DEBUG:>> "Content-Length: 317[\r][\n]"
Mon May 13 15:33:08 EDT 2013:DEBUG:>> "Host: api.test.com[\r][\n]"
Mon May 13 15:33:08 EDT 2013:DEBUG:>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Mon May 13 15:33:08 EDT 2013:DEBUG:>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: When you say Auth Headers are not set correctly have you tried to inspect the request to see how the raw request looks like? Also try to perform a call to the Java Service from a Java client and then inspect the raw request. The comparison between the raw request should give you an idea. Also you might need to set the Profile to 1.1 explicitly on your client. This link might be helpful as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bursteg/archive/2008/07/19/how-to-call-a-java-ee-web-service-from-a-net-client.aspx

Comment: Included the expected header. I'm able to call the web service correctly without SSL (the default httpBinding works fine and sends the correct header) but I'm not able to properly query the service when it is running with SSL transport + basic auth.

Comment: Can you try BasicHttpBinding with Security Mode = Transport and Message ClientCredentialType as Username. Dont explicitly set other properties. If it was via Config it would be something like: <basicHttpBinding><security mode="Transport"><message clientCredentialType="Username"/></security></basicHttpBinding>

Comment: @Rajesh I've tried your suggestion, the header is not included and the java service return access denied to operation.

Comment: Can you try adding the service using Add Web Reference and then try to invoke the service and capture the raw Request so that you can compare it against your code generated request.

Comment: The service was added by using Add Reference (created from wsdl) and the requests I included was the raw Request header from two different clients. One from WCF program and the other from SoapUI.

Comment: Can you try to capture the request using either Fiddler/Wireshark.

Comment: thanks for the link to the header workaround